# How to append 'strip_tags' to all db select queries automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, strip-tags

I have this in my php db.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
  if (!is_array($value)){
   $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
  }
}
```

First is my db connection and then a simple `foreach` to remove html tags from all POSTs. this page is included in all others that need a db connection.

Can I change this function to apply 'strip_tags' to all mysqli selects (instead of posts) and remove all tags there?

e.g.

```
1. db connection,
2. foreach/function to remove all tags from any mysqli select,
3. mysqli select query (with no html tags as result).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrapp it in a function :

```
function wrapp($sql){
  // You could add more stuff to change like htmlspeciclchars
  return strip_tags($sql);
}
```

You could call this function every time you do an query.

```
$mysqli->query(wrapp($sql));
```

If you want to work aroudn ith your connection even more it could be wise to build a class for it and implement functiosn like the one above in that. As far as I know there is no way to do this automaticly without calling a function or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of doing it automatically. You can do something like this:

1. db connection,
2. Prepare SQL query
3. Foreach all params, clean tags,
4. bind param Execute query

Other option is to use some ORM. For example [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) allows to specify function which is called before you save an entity. You can strip tags there.